# In C#, how do I use generics with two different types?

Tags: c#, generics

I have some classes that are created and maintained by Entity Framework. These classes represent tables in my DB. In two of these tables, I have very similar fields. For example (pseudo-objects):

```
public class RandomObject1
{
    int Identifier { get; set; }
    int ObjectType { get; set; }
    int SourceID   { get; set; }
    string OriginationPont { get; set; }
    string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    decimal Cost { get; set; }

    int OtherThing1 { get; set; }
    int OtherThing2 { get; set; }
    int OtherThing3 { get; set; }
}

public class RandomObject2
{
    int Identifier { get; set; }
    int ObjectType { get; set; }
    int SourceID   { get; set; }
    string OriginationPont { get; set; }
    string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    decimal Cost { get; set; }

    double CashValue1 { get; set; }
    decimal Snowman2 { get; set; }
    int BigFurryTree3 { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the first few fields of these two objects are the same, and the processes for populating those fields are also the same. Normally in these situations I would have an interface that declares just the first few fields so that I can pass this object as an interface to various processes.

However, in this case, **I don't control the code that builds these classes**, and really don't want to have to edit the resulting .cs files from the Entity Framework every time it is regenerated.

I was wondering if there is a slick way that I am missing to use generics to do something like the following:

```
// This method will populate SourceID, OriginationPoint, PhoneNumber and Cost
public void GenerateOriginationInformation<T>(ValidationInformation info, T objectToManipulate) where T : RandomObject1 || RandomObject2
{
    objectToManipulate.SourceID = GenerateSourceID(info);
    objectToManipulate.OriginationPoint = GenerateOriginationPoint(info);
    objectToManipulate.PhoneNumber = FindPhoneNumberByOrigination(info);
    objectToManipulate.Cost = DetermineCostBySourceAndOrigination(info);
}
```

Right now, I have to build an entire object/layer that will populate and return the correct object, but results in me doing most of the code for these things twice!

```
public void GenerateOriginationInformation(ValidationInformation into, RandomObject1 objectToManipulate) 
{
    objectToManipulate.SourceID = GenerateSourceID(info);
    objectToManipulate.OriginationPoint = GenerateOriginationPoint(info);
    objectToManipulate.PhoneNumber = FindPhoneNumberByOrigination(info);
    objectToManipulate.Cost = DetermineCostBySourceAndOrigination(info);
}

public void GenerateOriginationInformation(ValidationInformation into, RandomObject2 objectToManipulate) 
{
    objectToManipulate.SourceID = GenerateSourceID(info);
    objectToManipulate.OriginationPoint = GenerateOriginationPoint(info);
    objectToManipulate.PhoneNumber = FindPhoneNumberByOrigination(info);
    objectToManipulate.Cost = DetermineCostBySourceAndOrigination(info);
}
```

At first, this doesn't look too bad, but this code is highly over-simplified for the purposes of explanation and brevity. Is there a cleaner way to use generics to get the two methods to work as one since I can't implement an interface?

Comment: `I don't control the code that builds these classes, and really don't want to have to edit the resulting .cs files from the Entity Framework every time it is regenerated` <= is it a `t4` template file that does this? If so you can edit these to make them `partial` and then you can create a code file next to the generated files with a `partial` as well in which you make the type implement an interface. This would be a nice solution because the T4 template (or whatever process) does not have to know anything about the interface, just mark the class as partial and that is it.

Comment: No. it is EDMX 4. It doesn't use a t4 template. The EDMX in quesiton is used in almost every project we have here, and switching it to T4 would be "too high of a risk" (management's terms) to do for this project.

Comment: I would create DTO classes which are mapped from the EF classes. Then I would back both of those DTO classes with interfaces and that is what I would use as the generic constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`I don't control the code that builds these classes, and really don't want to have to edit the resulting .cs files from the Entity Framework every time it is regenerated`

> answer in comment: "it is EDMX"

The generated classes from your EDMX designer are partial by default (*no additional work necessary by you*) so you can create a code file next to the generated files with a `partial` as well in which you make the type implement an interface.

Generated class

```
public partial class RandomObject1
```

Your code file placed in the same project

```
public partial class RandomObject1 : ICommonInterface
```

Comment: BINGO! That's the part I wasn't grasping. Thank you!!

Comment: @Jerry - glad to help! I checked, they are partial by default (*at least in Ef5+ they are*) so nothing you have to do in the designer at all. You can just create the new code file as mentioned above :)

Answer (score 5):

The classes that are generated by Entity Framework are probably "partial". This means that you can write your own partial class to add features of your own to that generated class.

Such as this:

```
public partial class RandomObject1: ICommonInterface
{
}
```

With "ICommonInterface" an interface that specified the shared properties.